# How to refuse certain ip's in a java server

Tags: java, ip, block

Is there a way to block incoming connections to a java server if the client has a certain ip address?

Comment: Why don't you use the operating system's tool for doing this? Blocking an IP address with iptables in Linux is an easy job for the admin.

Comment: In code? What "java server"? Your own? Someone else's? What have you looked at/tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accept the connection, then get the `Socket` for that connection.  After that, it's a simple as calling `socket.getInetAddress()` and deciding if you want to reply with data or close the socket.

Beware, due to the prevalance of NAT, you might not be able to really differentiate who is connecting to you, as the request may have been rewritten (by NAT) to appear to come from a gateway machine instead of an end-client.

If this is an attempt to provide a "slightly more secure" set of connections, remember that IP addresses are trivially spoofed, and there are no real barriers from someone else setting their machine to have your IP address.